# Rip and scale Blender

Tags: scale

I have a problem. I need to rip and scale all of them. It suppose to be like this.

[image]

But I can't do that with the last one. It becomes no longer symmetrical.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have probably activated *Proportional Editing*. Hitting <kbd>O</kbd> should revert the behaviour.